# ArcGIS Server connection error for feature layers

Tags: arcgis-server

I get the following error when trying to access my hosted feature services from ArcGIS Server: "Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." Other service types (Image layers, Scene layers) are working fine. This error appeared suddenly and everything was working fine before.

What might be causing it?

Comment: be sure your firewall has a rule allowing all the correct ports, refer to this documentation http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/windows/ports-used-by-arcgis-server.htm